# Windows Azure SDK returns unknown AccountType: undefined

Tags: azure

I'm trying to login via Windows Azure SDK on OSX.
But I could not login because had gotten an error when I login: "Server returned an unknown AccountType: undefined".
My Azure account is a Visual Studio Premium with MSDN.
Also, the account has a spending limit yet, but I can create a Web Sites on Azure portal.
Could you tell me what is wrong?

### My work is here:

```
$ azure -v  
0.8.2  
$ azure login  
info:    Executing command login  
Username: MY_AZURE_ACCOUNT  
Password: **********  
If you choose to continue, Azure command-line interface will cache your authentication information. Note that this sensitive information will be stored in plain text on the file system of your computer at /Users/awwa/.azure/azureProfile.json. Ensure that you take suitable precautions to protect your computer from unauthorized access in order minimize the risk of that information being disclosed.  
Do you wish to continue: (y/n) y  
+ Authenticating...                                                            
error:   Server returned an unknown AccountType: undefined  
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err  
error:   login command failed
```

---

### azure.err is here:

```
Wed Apr 30 2014 21:40:30 GMT+0900 (JST):  
{ [Error: Server returned an unknown AccountType: undefined]  
  stack: [Getter/Setter],  
  __frame:   
   { name: '__7',  
     line: 171,  
     file: '/usr/local/azure/lib/commands/account.js',  
     prev: undefined,  
     active: false,  
     offset: 35,  
     col: 31 },  
  rawStack: [Getter] }  
Error: Server returned an unknown AccountType: undefined  
    at Logger.createError (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/log.js:196:13)  
    at /usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/token-request.js:366:35  
    at UserRealm._parseDiscoveryResponse (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/user-realm.js:234:3)  
    at /usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/user-realm.js:263:12  
    at Request._callback (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/util.js:116:5)  
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/node_modules/request/request.js:121:22)  
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)  
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/node_modules/request/request.js:978:14)  
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)  
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/node_modules/request/request.js:929:12)  
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/adal-node/node_modules/request/request.js:929:12)  
    at __7 (/usr/local/azure/lib/commands/account.js:206:31)
```

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The azure login method only works with organizational account. if you use a MSAccount, you should use "azure account import" and .publishsettings file.

see also:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/

Comment: Thank you. I had not understood what is "organizational account".

Comment: I could create Web sites from CLI by using "azure account import".